# Volumes of revolution (annular cross sections)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have been asked to find the volume of the solid of revolution when the region bounded by the curve $y=x(4-x)$ and the $x$ axis is rotated about the $y$ axis.

I am confused because the outer and inner radii share the same equation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the method of Cylindrical Shells. It *can* be done by slicing, but is more complicated that way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ok, I'll look into that method (I actually need to learn it soon too). But if you can, could you show me how to do it by slicing, as I am revising for a test which may ask for a particular method to be used, and I am interested in the process for more difficult questions like this one

Comment: What you asked for has just been done in the answer by reluctant mathematician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=x(4-x)$, with $0\leq x \leq 4$

Solving for x (using the quadratic formula) yields

$x=2\pm\sqrt{4-y}$, with $0\leq y \leq 4$

For the "inner radius", use the negative sign.
For the "outer radius", use the plus.

Comment: Thank you, are the limits on $x$ just due to the specified area?

Comment: yes. the lower boundary is y=0, which happens at x=0, x=4.

Comment: coincidentally, the max and min values of y are also 0 and 4.